# Azure - How do I create a dashboard graph to monitor traffic from an on-prem source IP?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-log-analytics, azure-nsg

I have a dashboard with my Azure VMs. I have metrics graphs to show the inbound network activity to those VMS. I would like a graph that shows the inbound traffic to a specific VM from a specific set of on-prem IPs. I would have thought that this would be achievable with Network Analytics, NSG Flow Logs or similar, but have spent hours without luck trying to find it.

Comment: do you want to show the inbound source IP to the Azure VM?  Can you click on 
TRAFFIC VISUALIZATION--inbound---Benign in the Network Watcher | Traffic Analytics
?  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @NancyXiong Yes! Thank you. I had no idea I could click that. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the inbound source IP to the Azure VM via clicking on **TRAFFIC VISUALIZATION**---inbound---Benign/Allowed/ in the Network Watcher | Traffic Analytics.

[image]

To go to the log search.

[image]